# Download excel sheet query result without writing file coldfusion

Tags: excel, coldfusion

I have a simple query whose results I am looking to download into excel on click of a button without writing the file to the disk.A gist of what I am doing.

```
<cfquery name="qtest" datasource="xyz">
select a,b,c from table
</cfquery>

<cfspreadsheet action="write" fileName="test.xls" query="the_jobfeed" overwrite=true />
<button>click here </button>
```

I have figured that its ok to write the file to the disk. Hence I am doing the above. But how do I conserve the query columns case on the excel sheet.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the stub of a [SpreadSheetService.cfc](https://gist.github.com/iknowkungfoo/1298ef5a65275163c70ad737743c2adc) that will convert a query to an excel file w/o writing it to a web-accessible folder.

The main function, `createFromQuery` takes 3 parameters:

1. data (query object)
2. xlsx (boolean, xls [false, default] or xlsx [true])
3. fileName (string, uses a UUID if empty.)

This service uses the server's temp directory as the location to create, compile and read the file to the brower. Once the file has been read into memory, the physical file is deleted from the temp directory to ensure that no other process can access it.

The core of the code:

```
<cftry>
    <cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#config.full_temp_name#" query="config.q" />
    <cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#config.full_temp_name#" name="local.xls" />
    <cffile action="delete" file="#config.full_temp_name#" />

    <cfif len(arguments.fileName) GT 0>
        <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#arguments.fileName#.#config.extension#" />
    <cfelse>
        <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#config.temp_name#.#config.extension#" />
    </cfif>
    <cfcontent type="application/msexcel" variable="#spreadsheetReadBinary(local.xls)#" reset="true" />
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" output="console" />
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Test code:

```
<cfset oSS = new SpreadsheetService() />

<cfquery name="testData" datasource="{your_dsn}">
    SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.Some_Table ORDER BY id DESC
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
    #oSS.createFromQuery(testData, false, "My Safe Excel File")#
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used variations of this snippet for a while:

```
<cfset sheet = SpreadSheetNew()>
<cfset SpreadsheetAddRow(sheet, "foo,bar")>

<!--- stream it to the browser --->
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=foo.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" variable="#SpreadSheetReadBinary(sheet)#">
```

Comment: where will the query result go in the above snippet

Comment: You will have to add programming code to populate the spreadsheet with your query results.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. The column headers on the excel sheet are all upper case even though I have the query columns as case sensitive , as this excel sheet will be used for further processing the headers are case sensitive. I know queryName.getMetaData().getColumnLabels() can be used to get the actual column names, but how do I use this in my excel sheet? Updating the question with what I have till now.

Comment: Your google search string is `ColdFusion spreadsheet functions`.